# Making a function which takes char* exception-proof

Tags: c++, beginner, strings, error-handling

I should preface this question by saying that I'm a Java programmer working on my first C++ application, so perhaps there are certain obvious things I don't know.

Some background on the problem:

Our application had data read from a socket stored in a character array, which was a fixed length message header, containing various fixed length fields i.e.:

```
char[15] data;
```

The field positions were 0-5,6-7,8-10,11-13 (the last char is a delimiter). The class which wrapped this header offered convenience functions to retrieve the values for each field:

```
    int ApiHeader::msg_size(void)
    {
        return std::atoi(std::string(data, 6).c_str());
    }

    int ApiHeader::msg_type(void)
    {
        return std::atoi(std::string(data,6,2).c_str());
    }

    int ApiHeader::msg_subtype(void)
    {
        return std::atoi(std::string(data,8,3).c_str());
    }

    int ApiHeader::seqno(void)
    {
        return std::atoi(std::string(data,11,3).c_str());
    }
```

I was trying to leverage the `std::atoi` which requires a c-string, but I needed to "slice" the character array into the sub-arrays which contained each separate field, which I did by constructing a string built from the positions in the `data` array for each field.

The code worked fine, but a user who was doing some code analysis pointed that the `msg_subtype()` function (and the 2 other similar ones), were actually unintentionally creating an extra string object.

They were invoking this constructor:

```
basic_string(const basic_string& other, 
              size_type pos, 
              size_type count = std::basic_string::npos, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So the code was first constructing a new string to turn the `char[]` to a `string&`, and then it was constructing another string invoking the `string(string&, int, int)` constructor.

I redesigned the code to be more efficient:

```
int atoi(char* string, int start, int length)
{
    double result = 0;
    char* index = string + start*sizeof(char);
    for(int i=length;i>0; i--)
    {
        result += (*index++ - '0') * pow((float) 10, (float) (i-1));
    }
    return (int) result;
}
```

There are no strings constructed, and it just iterates the part of the `data` array specified.  The problem is that this code *requires* that there is no way to detect whether the user passed bad values for `start` and `length`.  (I'm not exactly sure what happens if user passes a length outside of the array.  In my unit test, I just saw it got an uninitialized value).

What can be done to make this code more exception proof?

Some ideas I have are:

- If `*index` is not within valid range ('0' to '9'), break out of the loop.
- Same as above, except throw an `Exception` (which at least lets user know something went wrong).
- Just document the method to tell user that if values are bad, behavior is "undefined" (I have seen some methods documented this way).

What would be the best C++ way of handling this issue? Or is there a completely different approach which should be used for this function?

Comment: Do you have to call these functions multiple times for a single header? Have you considered having a couple of `int` variables in your `ApiHeader` class (assuming it's a class and not a namespace). That way, you only have to do the work of extracting from the array once.

Comment: These functions are only called once per message.  The data array is the header for a message.  The socket reads the bytes directly into that array.

Comment: In your 2nd update the test `length > sizeof(unsigned int)` is invalid. You are comparing the length of the ascii representation with the size of the binary result. Also note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a question: why do you care that an extra string is being created?  Is this function used **a lot**.  If not, then I see no need to change.

But beyond that, although I don't know about C++ cleverness, is your replacement function so much more efficient?  You are calling `pow` repeatedly and using floating point to do an integer job.  Here is an alternative that would be cheaper.  It returns 0 on success, 1 on failure (bad string) and the number desired is output in `result`.   Notice that `string` is `const`.

```
int my_atoi(const char* string, int start, int length, long *result)
{
    char copy[length+1];
    memcpy(copy, string + start, length);
    copy[length] = '\0';
    char *end;
    *result = strtol(copy, &end, 0);
    return (*end != '\0');
}
```

You might also omit the `start` parameter and call with

```
my_atoi(string+start, length, &res);
```

Comment: Rather than return true/false. I would make it return a pointer one past the last character read. The function can then be used to parse integers out of the middle of a string. If they also want to test that all characters have been used they just de-reference the pointer.

Comment: VLAs are not legal in C++.